# Background-image does not load CSS, DJANGO

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to load this image from css but the image does not display, the css is in /static/css/styles.css and the image is in /static/imagenes/proyecto1.jpg

```
.Project:first-child{
  background-image: url('../imagenes/proyecto1.jpg') ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I want to get the image to be able to be displayed, here is the html and css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 ;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);

}

h1{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #f9cccc;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {font-size: 2em;}
h3 {font-size: 2em}
p {font-size: 1em;}


input {
  width: 20em;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
}
textarea{
  width: 25em;
  height: 10em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #f9cccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000000;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: #FF69B4
}


.color-acento{color: #d1553f;}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.toggle-menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .toggle-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}


.main-menu{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.main-menu--show{
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.toggle-menu__checkbox{
  display: none;
}

.toggle-menu__checkbox:checked + .main-menu {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-menu  {
    flex-direction: row;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.main-menu__item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.main-menu__link {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}


header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100vh;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../imagenes/fondo1.jpg");
  filter: blur(8px);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}


#hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#hero .img-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;

}

#hero .img-container p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  
}


#foto-personal {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


#about-me .container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 150px 12px;
}


#about-me p {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;  
}

#about-me button {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}

#skills {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #3a2a2d     ;
}

#skills .column1 img {
  margin-left:2.5em ;
  padding: 1em;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#skills .column2 img {
  margin-left:2.5em ;
  padding: 1em;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
#skills h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2d8d8;

}

#skills img {
  transition: 1s;
}

#skills img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: 1s;
}

#Projects .Project {
  
}

.Project:first-child{
  background-image: url('../imagenes/proyecto1.jpg') ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Project:nth-child(2){

}

.Project:nth-child(3){
```

}

HTML:

```
<section id="Projects">
   <div class="container"/>
     <h2> Projects </h2>
     <div class="Project">
       <h3>Proyecto 1 </h3>
      </div>
       <div class="Project">
        <h3>Proyecto 2 </h3>
       </div>
       <div class="Project">
         <h3>Proyecto 3 </h3>
       </div>
      <button>More Projects</button>
     </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to use an absolute path to specify the location of the image file from the root directory. The / at the beginning of the path indicates the root directory.

#### Try below

```css
.Project:first-child{
  background-image: url('/static/imagenes/proyecto1.jpg') ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, make sure that the file names are correct and the image file has the correct extension **(i.e., .jpg, .jpeg...).**